# Why don't have equal sign "=" after versioning declaration

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

In declaration for `aws_s3_bucket`, missing equal sign `"="` follow behind the versioning:

```
 resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
    bucket                      = "bucket1"
     region                      = "us-west-02"
     tags                        = {
         "Evironment" = "dev"
         "Name"       = "bucket1"
       }
     versioning {
         enabled    = yes
       }
   }
```

Comment: `tags` is an argument and `versioning` is a block: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/syntax.html

Comment: Also this doesn't hold true for Terraform 0.12 where the parser is stricter here. You now need the `=` there while pre 0.12 didn't care.